# How to fetch records count from Azure data lake analytics files (File like txt and CSV )

Tags: analytics, azure-data-lake

adl://rs06ipadl01.azuredatalakestore.net/FIA/RDS/old/BANNER/2018/06/15/old_Banner.csv

i need to fetch the records from above file.

Answer (score 2):

You can the built-in extractors like `.Csv` and `.Text` to get the file content then use `COUNT` to count the records.  A simple example:

```
DECLARE @inputFile string = @"input/input124.csv";
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"output/output.csv";

// Get the file
@input =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 int
    FROM @inputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv( skipFirstNRows:1 );     // skip header row if you have one


// Count the records
@output = SELECT COUNT(*) AS records FROM @input;


// Output the result
OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

Comment: How to fetch columns count from Azure data lake analytics files (File like txt and CSV )

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it's been useful to you.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, that is a separate question.  Please mark this one as answered and open a second one.