# How to fetch the column count from dat file in Azure data lake analytics files

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have different `Dat` and `CSV` files. it's containing more than 255 columns and delimiter as '|' and tab. How to fetch the column count. Anyone please share sample `U-Sql` code

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please show a verifiable, working example. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I also note you have not marked your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999796/how-to-fetch-records-count-from-azure-data-lake-analytics-files-file-like-txt-a) as answered.  is there a particular reason?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for how to mark questions as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was down voted, so I hope it is still OK to supply an answer (although I'm not including a code sample).

Extract just the first row in your file (using FETCH 1 ROWS) into a single column rowset. You should then be able to use String.Split to get a column count.